# Sorting a list in SAPUI5

Tags: sapui5

I have a doubt regarding SAPUI5 Sort method.

```
var sOrder = "asc"
oView.byId("myList").getBinding("items").sort(
        sOrder && new Sorter("LastName", sOrder === "desc")
);
```

In the above code, I have following doubts.

1. what exactly is **sort** method accepting?
2. what does the && mean to in this context and how it's affecting the sorting?

this is the project [Project link](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/sample/sap.ui.core.tutorial.odatav4.04/preview)

Please share your views

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1.** this is the model that is used in the [application](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/sample/sap.ui.core.tutorial.odatav4.04/preview): [sap.ui.model.odata.v4.ODataListBinding](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.odata.v4.ODataListBinding/). the method [sort()](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.odata.v4.ODataListBinding/methods/sort) of `sap.ui.model.odata.v4.ODataListBinding` accepts as optional argument one of those:

- `sap.ui.model.Sorter`
- `sap.ui.model.Sorter[]`

**2.** `&&`in this context means that if the first expression is convertable to `true` then return the second expression. therefore, if `sOrder` of `sOrder && new Sorter("LastName", sOrder === "desc")` is true then return `new Sorter("LastName", sOrder === "desc")`. but if the first expression is convertable to `false` then return the first expression.

this affects the sorting in so far that the `sap.ui.model.Sorter` of the second expression `new Sorter("LastName", sOrder === "desc")` gets only returned if `sOrder` is converted to `true`. it does not have a falsy value. hence, the `sort()` method of `sap.ui.model.odata.v4.ODataListBinding` gets only called and therefore the `sap.m.table` sorted if the first expression is not a falsy. falsy values are:

- `false`
- `null`
- `undefined`
- `0`
- `NaN`
- `''`
- `""`
- `document.all`

in the stated application you find `aStates = [undefined, "asc", "desc"]`and `var sOrder = aStates[iOrder]`. this means, `sOrder` gets `undefined`, `"acs"` or `"desc"`assigned. this means again, that in the context of `sOrder && new Sorter("LastName", sOrder === "desc")` the `sap.m.Table` gets sorted if `"acs"` or `"desc"` is assigned to `sOrder`.